# Replacement for filterby in vuejs 2

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using django with vue js. I am following a tutorial for vue js and they have used vuejs 1 and I wanted to use vuejs 2.

How to change this statement from vuejs1 to vuejs2?

```
v-for=" (story,index) in stories | filterBy 'Alex' in 'writer "
```

This is my whole code. I am using django so mind the curly braces are replaced by [[ value ]].

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Vue</title>
    <link href="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Let's hear some stories!</h1>
    <div>
        <h3>Alex's Stories</h3>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for=" (story,index) in stories | filterBy 'Alex' in 'writer " class="list-group-item">
                 [[index+1]]. [[ story.writer ]] said "[[ story.plot ]]"
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>John's Stories</h3>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li v-for=" (story,index) in stories | filterBy 'Alex' in 'writer " class="list-group-item">
                 [[index+1]]. [[ story.writer ]] said "[[ story.plot ]]"
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <pre>
            [[ $data | json ]]
    </pre>
</div>

</body>





<script src="/static/vendor/vue.js"></script>
<script>

    new Vue({
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        el:'.container',
        data:{
            stories:   [
                {
                    plot:'I crashed my car today!',
                    writer: 'Alex'
                },
                {
                    plot:'Yesterday,someone stole my bag!',
                    writer:'John'
                },
                {
                    plot: 'Someone ate my chocolate...',
                    writer: 'John'
                },
                {
                    plot: "I ate someone's chocolate!",
                    writer:'Alex'
                }
            ]
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method that will return the filtered list.

Here is an example

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
    },
    methods: {
        even: function (numbers) {
            return numbers.filter(function (number) {
                // your custom logic here
                return number % 2 === 0
            })
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in even(numbers)">{{ n }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: return number % 2 === 0

I want this (2) to be dynamic what I have to do for it? I want here any number which I will call like this "n in even(numbers,divisor)",the name even would be not appropriate then. But still that will fix my problem.

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter to your method. So you can have something like `myFilter: function (param1, param2) {  // my logic with param 1 and param2 }`, then in the template you call it with your values.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that can you give me a snippet ?

Comment: something like ```divisibleBy: function (numbers, divisor) {
    return numbers.filter(function (number) {
        return number % divisor === 0
    })
}``` and then `<li v-for="n in divisibleBy(numbers, 4)">{{ n }}</li>`